# Proportion Composite score for DV in rANOVA- Need Help Interpreting Results

Tags: confidence-interval, spss

In my design, I have 3 binary items for each condition (4 conditions total) meant to measure the same thing. All participants were in all conditions (repeated measures, 12 scores each).

I made a composite score for each participants for each condition (yes, I know, not advisable but this is the way I am doing it so work with me, please). I coded the items such that 0= small and 1= large. I then interpreted the composite score to mean the likelihood of choosing the large item. (With me so far?)

I ran a rANOVA using my 2 IV's as within subjects factors.

The output says that there are 2 main effects and an interaction (I can't post the image but I am basing this off of the table called "multivariate tests" with Wilks' Lambda, which is p<0.05 (as are all the other tests there).

However, when I look at some of the levels (either in the main effects or in the interaction), I see that the confidence interval contains 0.5 (which to me means that we the level does not provide us any more info about how likely it is to choose "large.")

Does the significance in the table I have shown here mean that the effects do exist?

Should I interpret the effect by looking at the individual levels? (i.e. <0.5 means more likely to choose large) and see if the confidence intervals overlap?

What does it mean if the table says a main effect with 2 levels is significant but one of the 2 levels has a confidence interval that contains 0.5?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why can't a difference of 0.5 be significant? it should depend on the variance of the estimates. If the standard error of the estimates are well below 0.5 say 0.1 or less then a p-value less than 0.05 is consistent with this result.

Comment: I understand that it is significant- I just don't know how to interpret that in light of the meaning of my proportion (aka likelihood to choose large). I thought that if the confidence interval were significantly over 0.5 then I would be able to say there is a preference for large (and vice versa for <0.5). However, 0.5 itself is problematic in those terms. Did I clarify my question?

Comment: In that case (responding to your comment) the issue you are addressing is not statistical. It has to do with what you would call a large enough difference to be important. This is very much a subject matter and data dependent issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology 'rANOVA' (and I suspect I'm not the only one) - does that refer to repeated measures ANOVA?

Comment: Please do not use replies to carry on a discussion, @Michael. Keep it in comments while the conversation focuses on clarifying the question; if it goes beyond that, please use chat.

Comment: @whuber I do not agree with what you did.  My original post was an answer to the original question.  Emily clarified that she was not questioning the signifcance of the value 0.5.  Based on her response I gave what I think is an adequate final asnwer to the question.  It is not a beginning of a discussion.  I think it was a bit presumptuous of you to immediately take it down and make it a comment.  I think it was appropriate to have as an answer that could be scored.

Comment: Yes. It means repeated measures ANOVA. @Michael- maybe you could answer the question then of how I deal with this subject matter in interpreting my results in an answer below? Thank you!

Comment: @Michael, I read three questions posed by the OP, but did not detect an answer to any of them in the two replies you posted. Yes, moving replies to comments is presumptuous. I do not like doing it. However, you have now placed so many comments in replies in so many threads that my default reaction--and that of the other mods, too--is to presume your short replies are comments unless they very clearly address the question that is asked. Please note, too, that writing multiple replies is rare and should be reserved for cases where you have radically different answers to offer.

Comment: @whuber I think that what you say may have been true in my first couple of weeks.  But lately i think I have conformed to posting replies that are answers and not comments and to editing answers to combine in new response to one answer as seems to be the preference on this site.  I think you can see from Emily's reply that she probably felt my response was a good answer.  I then took her invitation to add another answer to her newly posed question.

Comment: @whuber My first answer which you now also have moved to comments was perhaps more like a clarifying question than an answer but I also said " If the standard error of the estimates are well below 0.5 say 0.1 or less then a p-value less than 0.05 is consistent with this result." This directly answers "Does the significance in the table I have shown here mean that the effects do exist? " How can you say that it doesn't?!

Comment: @Michael Nothing prevents you to leave a comment first, and to convert it as a reply after clarification or confirmation from the OP. Often, this may help clarifying or refining a question so as to provide a better answer or arrange multiple replies into one. Thank you to remember these rules of use in future.

Comment: @chl I understand the rules and I think I follow them pretty closely but I still think that Bill went a little overboard in converting my answers  to comments.  If changes were needed I could have done them myself.  Also he claimed that neither response directly addressed any of the OPs three questions and that was clearly not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to treat this problem taking what is considered to be an important difference into account is in the initial design where the sample size is chosen.  Do not choose the sample size to be so large that the power to detect a difference of 0.5 is high.  Define the importance difference (maybe that is 0.9).  Then choose the sample size large enough to have power say of 95% to detect a difference of 0.9 but no larger.  Then the test will not have much chance of detecting unimportant differences such as 0.5.  The idea is that in the hypothesis testing framework you can incorporate what you consider to be a significant effect size into the design for the test.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My DV values are between 0 and 1 (percentage of people who picked "large")- how could I get a difference of 6? Also, I already ran the study with 34 participants.

Comment: Sorry.  I lost the context of the problem.  I will edit that to say 0.9.  My point is that you look at this in terms of hypothesis testing rather than confidnce intervals.  if in the context of your problem 0.5 is not a meaningful proportion then set up the design to have power to detect a sgnificant proportion (perhaps 0.9 or some other high value).  Then the chance of the test calling 0.5 significant is decreased.

Comment: @Emily I know that you did the experiment with 34 participants and got the results you described.  I was addressing the question as to how you might have initially set up the problem so as to detect only differences that you would consider meaningful.  This might have led you to choose fewer than 34 subjects for the experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Given the data as it is about all you can say is that a difference of 0.5 is statisticlly significant and the confidence interval provides a ange of likely values for the proportion.  If you like my answer you can approve it and upvote it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "difference of 0.5"? I thought we were talking about a mean, not a difference. As in, the likelihood to choose the large item is 50%. The 50% is statistically significant but can I then say that the 50% means that that given condition does not provide a preference for an item? Again, I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Yes I meant to say a proportion of 0.5 not a difference.

Comment: One last clarification- was that a "yes" also to my interpretation of the 0.5 in my last comment?

Comment: Yes meant that I agreed that the term I should have used was proportion and not difference.

Comment: Would you agree with my interpretation: "The 50% is statistically significant but... that the 50% means that that given condition does not provide a preference for an item."?

Comment: I think it show a large portion of the respondents prefer the item but not an overwhelming majority.  So something similar to what you wrote is what I would say.